# CVMFS file access slow, although file is in cache

Tags: linux, cache

I have a directory in which there is a symlink to a file on CVMFS. When I first boot up, and do `ls`, it takes a long time (~a minute). The reason is that `ls` does `fstat` on each file to determine what color to show it in; if I do `ls --color=no` it is instantaneous. So far, so well-known.

The problem is that the target of the symlink is definitely in cache. I accessed it very recently and there is no reason it should have been flushed. Also, it shows up in `sudo cvmfs_talk cache list`. Why does CVMFS still hit the net? I guess the cache probably expired and it wants to see whether the file is still valid, or redownload it. This is fine, except when I have a bad WiFi connection or are on a plane with no internet.

Is there any way to tweak the CVMFS cache? I'd like an option to set the timeout to a few seconds, or possibly to keep it from refreshing files (when I know they have not changed, or I have no connectivity).